# Is there a way to ignore cloudwatch alarms when they are triggered at night?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have alarms in `AWS Cloudwatch` but at night I keep getting `False positives` due to `low volumes`. How can I set up an `alarm` so that it only triggers at certain times of the day? Or how do you suggest approaching this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AWS CLI you can disable cloudwatch alaram using the following command:

```
aws cloudwatch disable-alarm-actions --alarm-names "alarm name"
```

And then enable it again using this command:

```
aws cloudwatch enable-alarm-actions --alarm-names "alarm name"
```

You scheduled this disable/enable using cronjob for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this by creating an EventBridge rule where you specify a cron or schedule expression that runs a lambda function.

Then, you can use your Lambda function to enable or disable an alarm (or even multiple alarms together) according to your desired schedules.

```
disable_alarm = client.disable_alarm_actions(AlarmNames=alarm_names)
```

Here's a good tutorial: https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-structure-for-enabling-disabling-alarms-in-batches-5c4f165a8db7

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I found that it is possible to create a `metric` based on a `Math expression` where I could say for example:

```
IF(Invocations > threshold, metric, 0)
```

And this will output `0` at night where the `Invocations volume` is `less than` the `threshold`.

Then I could create an `alarm` on top of this new `metric`.

Comment: Not sure if it answers the question, but it does provide an interesting alternative.